# ActiveMQ + Stomp: Multi-subscriber queue

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

I'm interacting with ActiveMQ via STOMP. I have one application which publishes messages and a second application which subscribes and processes the messages.

If I am writing messages to a **queue** I can be certain that, if I have two consumers, each message will only be processed once (because when a message is completed it is removed from the queue) - but is this functionality available from a topic?

For example; I have a third application which is a logger. I want the logger to receive each message the publisher emits, but I also want exactly one of two (or three or four etc…) of the processors to receive the message too.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

It occurs to me that a good way of doing this would be to have a topic which the publisher writes to, and a queue which the processors listen to, with something pushing every message from the topic onto the queue. Can ApacheMQ do this internally?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this internally in ActiveMQ using [Mirrored Queues](http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html) and also use [Virtual Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) for some other advanced routing semantics.  If you want to have the option of other EIP type messaging patterns then I'd recommend you look into Apache Camel which provides a whole host of EIP pattern functionality.